# How to use lambda function to sort a list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, lambda, tuples

I have tried below but, it shows "none" in the output. How to use lambda function to sort a list of tuples?

```
listoftuples = [('English', 88), ('Science', 90), ('Maths', 97), ('Social sciences', 82)]
arrange = lambda x : listoftuples.sort()
a = arrange(listoftuples)
print(a)
```

Comment: what's the point of calling `lambda x` if you don't use `x` at all

Comment: why on earth are you trying to use a lambda here? In any case, `list.sort` sorts the list in place and returns `None`, so `arrange` will *return `None`* and have the side effect of sorting the list you are referencing globally. But there's no point to such a function, lists **have that method already**. Also, **never assign the result of a lambda expression to a name** it defeats the entire purpose, and is officially against PEP8 style guidelines

Answer (score 3):

`sort` does not return a value, so assigning the outcome of `arrange` to a variable does not do what you think it does. Also, when defining the lambda, you need to call the sort function on the lambda parameter.

Change your code like so to get it to work:

```
listoftuples = [('TEnglish', 88), ('Science', 90), ('Maths', 97), ('Social sciences', 82)]
arrange = lambda x : x.sort()
arrange(listoftuples)
print(listoftuples)
```

For that matter, you don't really need a lambda at all, you could simply do `listoftuples.sort()` in this case